# Keys shortcuts, Java

Tags: java, hotkeys, jmenuitem

I want to add a hotkey to JMenuItem. I learned how to add key that look like CTRL+SOME_KEY. But what I need, is a triple hotkey. Somthing like CTRL+ALT+W. I want to add a hotkey to JMenuItem. But how should I create such hotkey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you see if this will work for you?

```
menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
        KeyEvent.VK_W, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK + ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control alt W"));
```

Comment: Close, but you don't use the plus signs in the key stroke string.